# How to handle nested dicts?

Tags: tcl

I am a bit confused. I've set up a dictionary - and a nested dictionary
here is its "layout"

```
dict for {key val} $Courses {
puts " the key = $key "
puts " the val = $val "
                        }
```

.
.
.

```
 the key = 044262
 the val = name tehen grade 91
 the key = 044148
 the val = name galim grade tbd2
```

and inside a "dict for" command I want to pull the grade value - I cant get it to work.
If I am outside the dict I can just use

```
set tmp [dict get $Courses 044262 grade]
```

but inside the dict for I cant get it to work...tried many combinations of $key or $val with or without the $ sign

what Am I doing wrong (and if someone can recommend a good book/online tuturial with problems for training it will be great!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your particular dictionary, each run through the loop has `$val` being a dictionary of its own. You can then just access using normal dictionary operations; for example:

```
dict for {key val} $Courses {
    puts " the key = $key "
    puts " the val = $val "
    # Iterate over contents
    dict for {k v} $val {
        puts "$k => $v"
    }
    # Picking out a particular key
    puts "The grade was [dict get $val grade]" 
}
```

Note that if you're updating, the updates are *not* written back to `Courses`; dictionaries are copy-on-write values, as is normal for Tcl. You have to do an update like this:

```
dict set Courses $key grade "Excellent, dudes!"
```

And also note that the iteration won't see the change (you took a logical copy when you started the `dict for`). If you really want to see the changes, you need to write the loop quite differently:

```
foreach key [dict keys $Courses] {
    puts " the key = $key "
    puts " the val = [dict get $Courses $key] "
    dict for {k v} [dict get $Courses $key] {
        puts "$k => $v"
    }
    puts "The grade was [dict get $Courses $key grade]"
    dict set Courses $key grade 1234567890
    puts "The grade is changed to [dict get $Courses $key grade]"
}
```

If things are getting much more complex than that, I'd seriously consider using an embedded database like SQLite to manage the data…

Comment: tnx brother. big help